# fixing matplotlib/numpy dependency hell in Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

I'm running Python 2.7.11 under Anaconda 2.0.0 (x86_64) on a MacBook.

Some weeks ago, as part of a process of getting OpenCV working, I downgraded `numpy` from wherever it was (unfortunately/stupidly I have no record) to 1.7.1.   I seem to remember this was necessary, and I do not want OpenCV to stop working, so I'm pretty sure I should now leave `numpy` where it is.

However, today I discovered that this has broken my `matplotlib`/`pylab`. When I do `import pylab` I get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 7
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)    
...
...
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

My question, therefore, is: how do I install (or roll back to) a version of `matplotlib` that's compatible with my existing `numpy`, **without** disturbing my existing `numpy`?

Here's where I've got so far: based on related `conda` questions on SO, I looked at the output of `conda list --revisions matplotlib` which includes:

```
...
2016-03-28 17:16:36  (rev 6)
     conda  {3.8.3 -> 4.0.5}
     conda-env  {2.0.1 -> 2.4.5}
     numpy  {1.8.1 -> 1.7.1}
     ...
```

Now I'm not sure how to interpret this but given the `numpy` version number looks like it's actually falling in contrast to all the other entries here, this sounds to me like a promising, "in March 2016 matplotlib realized it could fall back to an *earlier* version of its numpy dependency". However, when I ask for this revision:

```
conda install --revision=6 matplotlib
```

I'm told I already have it, and that its dependency is `numpy` 1.8:

```
Fetching package metadata: ....

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/jez/anaconda:
#
matplotlib                1.3.1                np18py27_1    <unknown>
```

So from here I'm not sure how to proceed. I've tentatively played with some variations on `conda install matplotlib`, but it clearly wants to mess with my `numpy` at the same time, so I have never pressed `y`.  Equally clearly, I'm out of my depth in `conda`, so would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the exact versions of any libraries you want in the `conda install` command. For example:

```
$ conda install numpy=1.7.1 matplotlib=1.3
```

If the versions are incompatible, the command will give you an error specifying exactly what the incompatibility is.

Comment: Thanks—that's it! What worked for me was to specify the version of the `numpy` dependency but leave the `matplotlib` version unspecified.  `conda` then figured out and reported the following change:  `matplotlib:   1.3.1-np18py27_1  --> 1.3.1-np17py27_0`